# Virtual Airline Dispatch Generator

Tags: php, mysql

This Code is old and I am trying to figure out how to improve it. I am considering running the distance function in MySQL, but it is a ***** to figure out for me due to my experience with arithmetic in MySQL.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
    $data = $_SESSION[$id]; 
    $airline = $data['airline'];
    $hub = $data['hub'];    
    $ident = $data['originAirport'];
    $type = $data['type'];

//Query for Origin Airport Details
$query_org = $db->prepare("SELECT `ident`, `name`, `latitude_deg`, `longitude_deg`, `elevation_ft` FROM `airports` WHERE `ident` = :ident");
$query_org->bindParam(":ident", $ident);
$query_org->execute();
$originDetails = $query_org->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$query_des = $db->prepare("SELECT `ident`, `type`, `name`, `latitude_deg`, `longitude_deg`, `elevation_ft` FROM `airports` WHERE `type` = :type");
$query_des->bindParam(":type", $type);
$query_des->execute();
$num = 0;
while ($destinDetails = $query_des->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $distance = distance($originDetails['latitude_deg'], $originDetails['longitude_deg'], $destinDetails['latitude_deg'], $destinDetails['longitude_deg'], "N");
    if ($distance >= $data['dismin'] && $distance <= $data['dismax']) {
        $a[$num] = array(
            'ident'         => $destinDetails['ident'],
            'type'          => $destinDetails['type'],
            'name'          => $destinDetails['name'],
            'elevation_ft'  => $destinDetails['elevation_ft'],
            'distance'      => $distance
        );
        $num++;
    }
}

$num = null;
$num = 0;

foreach ($a as $z) {
    $i = $z['ident'];
    $query_run = $db->prepare("SELECT `length_ft` FROM `runways` WHERE `airport_ident` = :ident");
    $query_run->bindParam(":ident", $i);
    $query_run->execute();
    $result = $query_run->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $length = $result['length_ft'];
    if ($length >= $data['minrunlen'] && $length <= $data['maxrunlen']) {
        $b[$num] = array(
            'icao' => $z['ident'],
            'name' => $z['name'],
            'distance' => $z['distance']
            );
        $num++;
    }

}


$count = count($b);



$int = rand(0, $count);

//Query for Flight_ID
$queryc = $db->prepare("SELECT `fid` FROM `dispatches` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
$queryc->execute();
$flight_id = $queryc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);    
if ($flight_id[0] !== 1000) {
    $flight_id = (int)$flight_id[0];
    $flight_id++;
} else {
    $flight_id = 1000;
}
$dispatch = array(
    'airline'       => strtoupper($data['airline']),
    'hub'           => strtoupper($data['hub']),
    'pid'           => $data['pid'],
    'pilot'         => $data['fname'].' '.$data['lname'],
    'email'         => $data['email'],
    'fid'           => $flight_id,
    'airframe'      => $data['airframe'],
    'datetime'      => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
    'connumb'       => md5(rand(0,9999999999)),
    'originICAO'    => $originDetails['ident'],
    'originName'    => utf8_encode($originDetails['name']),
    'destinICAO'    => $b[$int]['icao'],
    'destinName'    => utf8_encode($b[$int]['name']),
    'distance'      => $b[$int]['distance']."nm"
);
//Query for runway information
$destinICAO = $dispatch['destinICAO'];
$queryd = $db->prepare("SELECT `length_ft`, `width_ft`, `lighted`, `closed`, `le_ident`, `le_latitude_deg`, `le_longitude_deg`, `le_elevation_ft`, `le_heading_degT`, `le_displaced_threshold_ft`, `he_ident`, `he_latitude_deg`, `he_longitude_deg`, `he_elevation_ft`, `he_heading_degT`, `he_displaced_threshold_ft` FROM `runways` WHERE `airport_ident` = :ident");
$queryd->bindParam(":ident", $destinICAO);
$queryd->execute();
```

Any suggestions are helpful. I am not looking for anybody to rewrite the code. That is my job, but guidance is more what I am looking for.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You'll go far here with that kind of attitude. I hope you get some solid reviews.

Answer (score 1):

**Prepare once - execute multiple times**

Prepared statements not only prevent SQL injection, but also enable you to only prepare a statement once, and then execute it multiple times with different values for increased performance:

```
$query_run = $db->prepare("SELECT `length_ft` FROM `runways` WHERE `airport_ident` = :ident");
$query_run->bindParam(":ident", $i);

foreach ($a as $z) {
    $i = $z['ident'];
    $query_run->execute();
    [...]
}
```

**Naming**

- don't use short, non-expressive variable names. `a`, `z`, `i` (as non-loop variable), `b`, etc are not telling a reader much.
- use either camelCase or snake_case, but don't mix them.
- write out words. what's an `org` or a `des`? what is a `destin`? why is `ident` an `originAirport`?
- What's a `num`? (ok, a number, but what kind of number? Seems to be a counter, so `counter` would be more fitting. But what does it count?
- `int` is also not a very good name. It seems to be a random index? Then `randomIndex` would be better.

**Misc**

- variables which are only used in one place, and whos name doesn't really add anything can be removed. Eg `$count = count($b);` is not needed, just use this directly: `$int = rand(0, count($b));`
- if you split your code up into methods, it will be easier to read. You might have methods such as `getOriginAirport`, `meassureDistancesFrom`, `getFlightId`, `getRunwayInfo`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. It was very helpful. I will work on implementation this week. As for the variable names. I wasn't very creative back then. You obviously caught on to my lack of experience. But it would be better to turn this into a class. That would speed things up?

Comment: @Dave No, OOP wouldn't increase the performance of the code (sometimes, OOP actually adds a small(ish) performance overhead). But for larger projects, it definitely increases maintainability and readability if done correctly, so it's generally worth it.